# Can a managed package cease to depend on another managed package?

Tags: managed-package, isv

If I have a Managed Package with Namespace `ns2`, with package components that depend on / extend components in `ns1`, then `ns1` must first be installed in an org before `ns2` can be installed - as `ns2` has become an "extension" package of the `ns1` "base" package.

So my question is: if I remove the components in `ns2` that depend on `ns1`, and then push out a new version of `ns2`, will the new version of `ns2` still require `ns1` to be installed? I believe that the answer is YES, but I have not actually tried it before. Has anyone ever tried this?

Example scenario:

1. `ns1` has a `global virtual` Apex Class called `BaseController`
2. `ns2` has a `public` class called `NS2ControllerImpl` which extends `ns1.BaseController`
3. Since the `ns2` class is public, I can change the class signature so that it no longer extends `ns1.BaseController`
4. Assuming that this is the only remaining reference in `ns2` to `ns1`, if I push out a new version of `ns2`, will I be able to install `ns2` into an org without having `ns1` installed in that org?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have tried this before and can confirm I have seen it remove the dependency from the Dependencies page available from the Package details page. You might need to make sure the metadata files associated with your Apex, VF pages and components are updated. But this should work. Be careful though as you cannot put back those components or reuse their names. I have seen issues with shadow copies of them holding a package dependency in the past, but lately this seems to have been resolved.